# ajax mysql checkbox filter with multiple checkbox

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a checkbox filter which is having two filter box one for the Company name and other one is for Salary. There is one filter button. User can check one or more companies name but can select only one salary. When the user select salary and click on the filter button the query is working fine. But how to make query in which user can select either company name or salary or both.

### AJAX code

```
$(document).delegate('#filter_button','click',function(){
    var sal=$('#sal input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){return 
    $(this).val();}).get()
    var emp=$('#emp input:checkbox:checked').map(function(){return 
    $(this).val();}).get()

$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'autoload_jobs.php',
    data:{'salary':JSON.stringify(sal),'employer':JSON.stringify(emp)},
    success:function(data)
    {
       $("#all").hide();
       $("#result").show();
       $("#result").html(data);
    }
    });
});
```

### Below is the MYSQL query:

```
$sql_sal="select *,fe.id as jid,fe.job_title,fe.job_category,fe.exp_min,fe.exp_max,e.emp_company,e.emp_company,fe.job_desc,group_concat(DISTINCT jl.loc SEPARATOR ', ') as loc from jobs 
as fe INNER JOIN employer as e ON fe.emp_id=e.emp_id INNER JOIN 
`jobs_skills` as js ON fe.id=js.j_id INNER JOIN `job_loc` as jl ON 
fe.id=jl.j_id INNER JOIN 
`employer_details` as eds ON fe.emp_id=eds.emp_id where ";

if(isset($_POST['salary'])){
    ?><script>$('.all').hide();</script><?php
    $sal=$_POST['salary'];
    list($mins,$maxs)=explode(".",$sal,'2');
    $sql_sal .=" fe.max_salary BETWEEN '$mins' AND '$maxs' GROUP BY 
    jl.j_id";
 }
if(isset($_POST['employer'])){
     ?><script>$('.all').hide();</script><?php
     $emp=$_POST['employer'];
     $sql_sal .="AND e.emp_id='$emp' ";
}
$sql_sal .=" GROUP BY jl.j_id";
```